# PayPal Express Checkout for digital goods, not showing pay with credit card option

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I'm integrating paypal express checkout for digital goods into my website, and to show "***pay
 with credit card***" option , I set the paypal account optional to ON, through "***Profile -> More Options -> My Selling Tools -> Website Preferences***" , and set the parameters "***SOLUTIONTYPE***" and "***LANDING***" to "***Sole***" and "***Billing***", respectively , and it worked very well in the paypal sandbox, but when going live, the "***pay with credit card ***" option disappeared and paypal displayed "***login to paypal***" and "***create paypal account***" options, am i missing something?

Comment: Is this live somewhere we can test and reproduce the behavior?

Comment: I think that have to do with the cookies that paypal have set to your browser. Ether remove the cookies and try again, either use some browser that you never have been login on PayPal. If you have login to  your paypal acount and you have a cookie, then you may not see the pay with credit card.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, your PayPal account primary email address must be confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already stated you enabled SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole in your coding. 
Sometimes this happens if you have recently been logged in to your PayPal account. If you haven't tried clearing your cache and cookies, the other option out there would be to ensure your PayPal Account is enabled for Digital Goods. (Only if you are needing to use the Digital Goods API)
[Digital Goods Sign Up](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/digital-goods)

Once you have cleared your cache and cookies, ensured that you have signed up for digital goods (only if you are needing to use the Digital Goods API), this should resolve the issue.